# Regular expression to find pattern with insertion and deletion cross different lines?

Tags: bash

I have text file with following lines as example:

```
AZZKLMNANAKK
AZZLNAKK
AZLPMNNAK
```

I would like to write regular expression `(AZLN)`which allows me to search for specific pattern that is shared between different lines with specifying certain number of insertion and deletion.
Would someone can help me with that ?

Comment: Which string you want to search, please be more clear on same?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, I've updated it.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to search specific text in Input_file if yes then I added the answer, use simple `grep`.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by insertion and deletion here

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to do a simple search then use `grep` as follows.

```
grep "AZLN"  Input_file
```